# Multiple selection ain't working in Phpstorm 8 under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, ubuntu-14.04

New feature in Phpstorm 8 - multiple selection ain't working under Ubuntu 14.04, however, the hotkey ALT+J does work, but i cannot multiple select using ALT+Mouse left click, i have checked the keymap

```
Add or Remove caret is set to ALT+Button1 Click
```

Which seems okay. When i try to hold ALT and left click - nothing happens, i guess it's ubuntu related.

Comment: Yes, it's Ubuntu related -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/151252/altleft-click-how-to-remove-shortcut or similar

Comment: If you do not want to remove such shortcut from Ubuntu .. just change shortcut in PhpStorm

Comment: Which combination is safe to use?

Comment: No idea, sorry -- I'm not Ubuntu/Linux user. Here on Windows Alt+Click does the job for me and I have not thought about any other shortcut for it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I know this is old, but for anyone else that comes here if you don't want to remap it, you can hit **cmd(win key)+alt+click**, it won't be recognized as a move operation but phpstorm will just register the **alt+ button 1 click**.

Comment: This worked for me, to find the keybind, search for : Add or Remove Caret

Comment: You also need to use Shift+Alt+Win+Click if you want Shift+Alt+Click bound

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu. A workaround is to change the keymap to something else - for some reason Alt+Click is not being detected.

I changed mine to **Alt+Shift+Click** and it is working fine.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because Ubuntu, GNU/Linux based distros in general, uses the Alt + Click shortcut to move Windows from any location of the window, in contrast to Windows OS, when you can only move a window from it's title bar.

So when you hit Alt + Click in any window on Ubuntu, including PhpStorm's, the OS recognized it as a move operation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using **Ubuntu Gnome**, I solved this problem by disabling the **window action key** in **Gnome Tweaks** in **Windows** tab

Answer (score 3):

The other way around is to change Ubuntu's shortcut for alt + button 1.

- Open `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager)
- Go into "Window management" and then "Move your windows around"
- Find a setting whose label is something like "Start moving the window". Should be the first one.
- Assign whatever fits your needs

Tried in 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

on MACos, **Command+Alt+Shift+click** work

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File > Settings > Keymap**, then enter ***selection*** in the input search, then find **Select all Ocurrence**, then click right and select **Add keyboard shortcut** and select the combination that you wish, then accept changes and the OK.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 running PHPStorm 2018.1 the command will be *CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+Click*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***`Xfce`*** like `Xhubuntu`, all you have to do is to go to `settings > settings manager > window manager tweaks > accessibility` and select another key instead of `alt` to move the windows or choose `none` at all.

Answer (score -3):

I love the @Dstum workaround.

Here it is another one I came across without remapping:

`Click + Alt + Drag`

Lovely simple, although it doesn't work for multiple clicks..

EDIT
Just in case: this is not the same as `Alt + Click` !!